# Validating models against the parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I have two models, one is the parent of the other, and the parent accepts_nested_attributes_for and validates_associated the children.

However, some of my validations have an :if that needs to check one of the properties of the parent.

I was thinking that I could do something like this:

```
validates_presence_of :blah, :if => Proc.new{|thing| thing.parent.some_value.present?}
```

However, the 'parent' relationship doesn't appear to be setup at the time of validation (I would assume the children get instantiated and validated first.

Therefore is there any way of doing what I'm thinking of? Is it possible?

Comment: In many instances of this problem, you could simply move the validation to the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use before_update or before_create callbacks as per your need like this..

```
def before_update
  self.errors.add("Error Message") if self.parent.some_value.present?
  return false if self.errors.count > 0
end

def before_create
  self.errors.add("Error Message") if self.parent.some_value.present?
  return false if self.errors.count > 0
end
```

Comment: This works but a drawback is that the model will respond `true` when asked if `valid?` even if the value on the parent is not present.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of validation should work:

> validates_associated :children

But it won't

The reason is, as far as I understand, beause using `acceptes_nested_attributes_for` is creating nested objects straight to database via one transaction without passing any children validations.

What you can do here: write your own validation in parent model and validate creating children objects.

Comment: I think this was the case with ActiveRecord/Rails 2.3, but not in 3.1 or 3.2.  Child objects created by nested attributes are validated, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:inverse_of` option for the association on the parent, so the children will have a reference to the parent when they are built.

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, :inverse_of => :parent
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end

p = Parent.new :children_attributes => { 0 => { :child_attribute => 'value' } }
p.children.first.parent #=> shouldn't be nil anymore
```